# How to encode POP instructions in 8086?

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86-16, machine-code

I'm trying to encode the following few instructions in 8086.

I've learnt how the whole mod, reg, d, w and everything works. So, I can encode almost all the instructions like `MOV [BX + 1234H], DS` but I just cant seem to wrap my head around the PUSH and POP instructions?

`POP DS` Answer: 1FH

`PUSH AX` Answer: 50H

How do I encode these to binary?

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference. `POP DS` is explicitly listed as `1Fh`, it doesn't get easier than that.

Comment: But, I want to convert it myself. I know I've to look up the MOD table and the 8086 instruction format and I've done that but I can't convert these by myself.

Comment: You can't "convert it yourself". You need to look up the opcode. It's `1Fh`. End of story. `PUSH AX` is more interesting, as `PUSH r16` is `50+rw`. Consulting _Table 3-1. Register Codes Associated With +rb, +rw, +rd, +ro_ you can see `AX` is `0` so the machine code is `50h` and **not** `58h` that you claimed (which is `POP AX`).

Answer (score 3):

There are three different encodings for `pop` depending on what you want to pop.  If you want to pop a segment register, the encoding is `07` plus the number of the segment register shifted left by four places, so `07` for `pop es`, `17` for `pop ss` and `1f` for `pop ds`.  The instruction `pop cs` used to have opcode `0f`, but this was removed in the 80186 processor.  It is now the prefix for two-byte instructions.  You cannot `pop cs` anymore.  To pop `fs` or `gs`, use opcodes `0f a1` for `pop fs` and `0f a9` for `pop gs`.

If you want to pop a general purpose register, the encoding is `58` plus the number of the register.  The size of the register is 16 bits in a 16 bit operation mode, 32 bit in a 32 bit operation mode or 64 bit in a 64 bit operation mode.  It can be changed with a `66`.  In 64 bit mode, the high bit of the register number also goes into an optional REX prefix.

If you want to pop into a memory location, the encoding is `8f /0`, i.e. opcode `8f` with a modr/m byte where the register field holds value `0`.

Refer to the manual for details. (e.g. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop, or the full Intel PDF it was extracted from)